# Socket.io private chat using multiple rooms

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm creating my own chat application using socket.io and pure js and already created this: [Chat application](http://35.204.86.124:3000/).

Now, I want to add private chat feature into this and I am wondering how to do it.

What can be a good way to do it? Dynamically create a new room each time 2 users need to chat in private? But how the second user is going to be notified of the new room created, so that he can connect there? Maybe creating own room for every user would be a good idea?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Too broad.

Comment: Tokens? usernames? Whatever? Definetly not really related to programming

Comment: You create a new private chat room only when you have the two sockets that you want to put in it.  Then, you can just put them into it.  You don't have to "tell" the other user which room to go to, your server does that.  Then, you can tell both clients what room they are in and each message they send to the other can include that room id.